# Xampp refused connection

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I've put a PHP Laravel project in my xampp folder, and I configured it a bit :

```
<VirtualHost myproject.dev:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\public"
  ServerAdmin myproject.dev
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this in my system32/drivers/etc

```
 127.0.0.1  myproject.dev
```

The problem I have is that it doesn't show my google map ( I heard it's a problem with the port number) , so I tried changing it to a different port. I've went and changed Listen 80 to Listen newport,(changed the above port aswell) however I get connection refused with my new port. If I switch it back to 80 it works fine. Any idea why ?

Comment: Did you restart the Apache after port changed? If not maybe is worth to try. Also check if the port you enter isn't used from some other application.

Comment: Yes, I did restart and I've tried with 5 different ports, some of those I'm certain are not used by anything else

Comment: Not sure if its part of your problem, but assuming you are using an Apache that is IPV6 aware you shoudl also have `::1 myproject.dev` in the HOSTS file

Comment: Do you have the full error message you get back from google?

Comment: [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See xxxx for more details.
geoLocationInit @ map.js:17
(anonymous) @ map.js:13
c @ app.js:29
l @ app.js:29 This is all I'm getting

Comment: Well this answered the question.

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot to check my console, all is good now

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a private browser ? Sometimes when I use incognito mode it stops me receiving data from outside sources. Such as weather updates and google maps. Or if I pull in JSON data from my web server.

Comment: No, I'm not though

Comment: If I run the project via cmd : php -S localhost:8181 -t public for example and connect to localhost:8181 on the browser, the map shows up

Comment: ah okay, don't think I've had this problem before. Sorry I couldn't be more help. Hope you get it to work!